# count number of subsets with atmost k distinct elements

Tags: algorithm, set, subset, combinatorics

given a set of inetegers, count the number of subsets with atmost k distinct elements. 
eg: set is {1,1,2,3,3} and k = 2:

possible subsets are: 
{} - empty set
{1} 
{1} 
{2} 
{3} 
{3} 
{1,1} 
{1,2} 
{1,3} 
{1,3} 
{1,2} 
{1,3} 
{1,3} 
{2,3} 
{2,3} 
{1,1,2} 
{1,1,3} 
{1,1,3} 
{1,3,3} 
{1,3,3} 
{2,3,3} 
{1,1,3,3} 
my solution was to iterate all the possible subsets and check whether there are less k+1 elements.. but it was so slow.. O(2^n)

Comment: According to set theory, {1} is exactly identical to {1, 1}.  Is your definition of "set" the same as the definition in number theory?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Describing_sets

Comment: I think the notion you're looking for is a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). An array would be ordered.

Comment: Are {1, 3} and {3, 1} considered the same subset?  In set theory they are.

Comment: Are you looking for multisets or just sets? And wont {1} and {1} be the same set?

Comment: Check out the math at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets

Comment: Probably a clearer description is, given nonnegative integers k <= n and a function f from {1, ..., n} to colors, how many subsets S of {1, ..., n} satisfy |{f(x) : x in S}| <= k, i.e., have at most k colors present?

Comment: Or in more informal terms: Given an array, count the number of ways of selecting a subset of indices, such that the values at those indices form a set of cardinality less than or equal to k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compress your set of values to a representation like `S = [1:2, 2:1, 3:2]` where you just save the value and the count for every element and assign them some order. Let n be the size of the sequence S. You then have 2^count possibilities to select a subset for every value.

For every group you have to decide whether to take it or not. If you take it, the number of distinct values increases and you have 2^count - 1 possibilities to do so. If not, the number of distinct values stays the same.

This yields the following DP approach: Let f(i, k) be the number of ways to make decisions from index i on, given that you are only allowed to use k more distinct values.

The recurrence is

```
f(n, k) = 1   if k >= 0
f(n, k) = 0   if k < 0
f(i, k) = f(i + 1, k) + (2^count[i] - 1) * f(i + 1, k - 1)
```

Leading to an O(n * k) algorithm. The result will be f(0, k).